# Blocking facebook's Like button in firefox

Tags: firefox, facebook, privacy

Many sites today use widgets from facebook such as the Like button, list of friends who are fans of that site and so on. While it may be a nice feature, I perceive it to be a serious privacy intrusion, because facebook most likely stores information about which sites you visit.

I also heard that when you are not logged into facebook, it still tracks the sites you visit (probably with a cookie) and once you log in attaches the data to your real account.

For now, I want to keep using facebook, but I would like to block just these widgets so it can't track me. Is there any Firefox extension which could do that?

Comment: As this has been closed, see also [How can I block all Facebook elements/content](http://superuser.com/questions/220696/how-can-i-block-all-facebook-elements-content).

Comment: This is a very nice topic why did you close it!

Comment: [Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/) works fine too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1865) to block these items, just add the following two lines to the Adblock rules:

http://www.facebook.com/external/*

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/*

Block other:

Google plus: `https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js`
Tweet        `http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) script to remove Facebook Like buttons from any webpages. You can install the script from the following link: [Remove Facebook Like buttons](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/76037).

Answer (score 1):

With the extention [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) you can modify web pages to remove (or change/add) any content, so at least for not displaying them this could be used. However I am not sure of the exact order of events to when greasemonkey starts so it might be too late in order to avoid tracking.

There also appears to be a couple of plugings written to directly handle facebook:

- [Facebook Beacon Blocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10497/)
- [remove all facebook ads](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11556/)