# How can I block all Facebook elements/content

Tags: macos, firefox, privacy, blocking, facebook

I have no Facebook account. How to block all Facebook elements (not only like-button, but everything Facebook) on the rest of the Internet. I worry being tracked by Facebook. I am using Firefox on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 16):

You can add these lines to the file `/etc/hosts` on your computer to cut off access to all facebook content:

```
# Block Facebook
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1 static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 static.ak.connect.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1 www.connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1 apps.facebook.com
```

Comment: Another option would be to add those domain names in the [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722/) add-on.

Comment: Perhaps the content that you still see is not loaded from Facebook but rather from the site that you are on? If that is the case, editing /etc/hosts will still keep your Mac from sending any data to Facebook.

Comment: @fyodor78 link to the site ?

Comment: @Sathya, http://www.bradleymanning.org/category/activism/

Comment: @fyodor78 The small footer on [the screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Hu2dW.png) is rendered by HTML that is [from the site itself](http://www.bradleymanning.org/category/activism/). That HTML refers to the image `http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z5/r/3_oEy-UyyDE.png` but that can be cached [for almost a year](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http:%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Frsrc.php%2Fz5%2Fr%2F3_oEy-UyyDE.png). So I guess it has been taken from your browser's cache. What if you first clear your browser's cache?

Comment: @fyodor78 That's odd, it shouldn't be able to load the like list. Are you still able to load www.facebook.com?

Answer (score 7):

Since IPv6 started going live, it has made @mckeed's response incomplete. "::1" is the default feedback loop for IPv6. It needs to be added to each Facebook entry in `/etc/hosts`. Here's what mine looks like:

```
# Block Facebook IPv4
127.0.0.1   www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   facebook.com
127.0.0.1   login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   www.login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   www.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1   www.fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1   static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   static.ak.connect.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1   www.connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1   apps.facebook.com
# Block Facebook IPv6
::1 www.facebook.com
::1 facebook.com
::1 login.facebook.com
::1 www.login.facebook.com
::1 fbcdn.net
::1 www.fbcdn.net
::1 fbcdn.com
::1 www.fbcdn.com
::1 static.ak.fbcdn.net
::1 static.ak.connect.facebook.com
::1 connect.facebook.net
::1 www.connect.facebook.net
::1 apps.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 4):

[Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) is available for Firefox and Safari, it blocks a laundry list of trackers including Facebook. If you want to you can tell it specifically what to block and what not to block.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a complete solution. If you have Adblock, then you can use the filter at http://adblockplus.org/en/subscriptions
Scroll down to the "Miscellaneous" section and then subscribe to the "Antisocial" filter. That blocked it for me.
Combined with mckeed's answer, this might block all of Facebook.

The antisocial filter blocks Twitter and other services too, so it might not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only Firefox to be affected, you could add the domain list [from mckeed's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/220696/how-can-i-block-all-facebook-elements-content/220700#220700) to a custom filter in [Adblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1865/).

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X, [GlimmerBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/) can work as a proxy for all your browsers. It blocks Facebook by subscribing to [the right filter](http://glimmerblocker.org/wiki/Filters):

> Title: Facebook 'Like' Disabler
>
> Author: Adam Stamper
>
> Description: This filter prevents autoloading of 'Like' buttons & other social gadgets from Facebook servers. Instead a link appears to let you enable each gadget, giving you control over how much Facebook knows about your web usage.
>
> URL: http://visuao.net/facebook/glimmer.xml

Note that GlimmerBlocker does *not* work for HTTPS sites, as the browser will then send encrypted traffic through the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FaceBookBlocker](http://webgraph.com/resources/facebookblocker/)

> **How did we get here?**
>
> We’re beginning to feel overwhelmed by
>   the frequency with which Facebook
>   links are starting to appear on many
>   of the sites we visit in our daily
>   routines, so we decided to do
>   something about it.
>
> **What does it do?**
>
> This browser extension stops Facebook
>   social plugins—including those within
>   iFrames—from running on sites other
>   than Facebook itself. This includes
>   ‘Like’ buttons, ‘Recommended’ lists,
>   and should also stop any Facebook
>   scripts from tracking your browsing
>   history.
>
> **What about Facebook Connect?**
>
> Don’t worry: sites that use Facebook
>   Connect for sign in purposes, or that
>   use Facebook as a conduit for other
>   functionality will continue to work as
>   expected.

Comment: link to facebook blocker gives 404

Answer (score 1):

With [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/master/README.md#philosophy), [AdBlock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/), or any other browser extension that can use AdBlock Plus filter lists, you can install the [**Anti-Facebook Filters**](https://www.fanboy.co.nz/), which aims to block Facebook content on non-Facebook websites.

You might also want to look at the **[Fanboy Annoyance Block List](https://www.fanboy.co.nz/)**, which aims to...

> ...Block Social Media Content, In page Pop-Ups and other annoyances; thereby substantially decreasing web page loading times and uncluttering them.

Aside from social media content, it also blocks in-page popups, newsletters, unnecessary links, self promos and other content that clutters sites unnecessarily.

You could install the **[Fanboy Ultimate List](https://www.fanboy.co.nz/filters.html)**, which combines the Annoyances block list with [EasyPrivacy](https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) (blocks trackers), and [EasyList](https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) (main ad blocking list). Note that you don't need to install the Annoyances block list if you already have the Ultimate list installed.