# Adding items to /etc/hosts doesn't block Facebook on Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, blocking, browsing

I have seen that I can't block facebook by adding 127.0.0.1 on Windows 8! Searching on Internet let me know that I should use IP V6 loopback for blocking facebook. Now I have added the following lines to my etc/hosts file but it still doesn't work for me.

Here, there is a similar question but for apple and not for windows 8 [Why can't I block Facebook using /etc/hosts on Mountain Lion (OS X)?](https://superuser.com/questions/544789/why-cant-i-block-facebook-using-etc-hosts-on-mountain-lion)

```
# Block Facebook IPv4
127.0.0.1     facebook.com
127.0.0.1     www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   www.login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   www.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1   www.fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1   static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   static.ak.connect.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1   www.connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1   apps.facebook.com
# Block Facebook IPv6
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
fe80::1%lo0     facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0     www.facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0     login.facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0     www.login.facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0     fbcdn.net
fe80::1%lo0     www.fbcdn.net
fe80::1%lo0     fbcdn.com
fe80::1%lo0     www.fbcdn.com
fe80::1%lo0     static.ak.fbcdn.net
fe80::1%lo0     static.ak.connect.facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0     connect.facebook.net
fe80::1%lo0     www.connect.facebook.net
fe80::1%lo0     apps.facebook.com
```

Comment: You do know it's not `/etc/hosts` on a Windows-machine? (It's `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. And you **can** use `::1` instead of the `fe80::1%lo0` on Windows.

Comment: Ya! I surely know that it's C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and the question implicitly means that it works for other sites except facebook. But I didn't know that in Windows I only should use ::1 . Using ::1 it worked well. Thank you a lot @Rik!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to the comment of @Rik. I had used the code that had been made for Apple operating systems, while in Windows I should have used `::1` instead of `fe80::1%lo0`. Anyway changing the file in this way solved the problem.

```
127.0.0.1     facebook.com
127.0.0.1     www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   www.login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   www.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1   www.fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1   static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   static.ak.connect.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1   www.connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1   apps.facebook.com


# Block Facebook IPv6
#fe80::1%lo0     localhost
::1     facebook.com
::1     www.facebook.com
::1     login.facebook.com
::1     www.login.facebook.com
::1     fbcdn.net
::1     www.fbcdn.net
::1     fbcdn.com
::1     www.fbcdn.com
::1     static.ak.fbcdn.net
::1     static.ak.connect.facebook.com
::1     connect.facebook.net
::1     www.connect.facebook.net
::1     apps.facebook.com
::1     edge-star6-shv-02-ams2.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is missing `facebook.com` and `www.facebook.com` for IPv4. Any request for `facebook.com` or `www.facebook.com` that is using IPv4 will still be looked up externally and work as usual. Add these lines:

```
127.0.0.1     facebook.com
127.0.0.1     www.facebook.com
```

Comment: That's right but those two lines don't solve any problems. Thus I had those two lines in the long list of all other blocked websites I haven't reported here. Thanks. I correct it in the question!