# x-lite dns lookup from local hosts file

Tags: dns, xlite

I've added a domain to my local /etc/hosts file on osx 10.9.2. if I ping the domain, it resolves to the configured ip in the /etc/hosts. If I put the domain into the "Domain" field for a SIP Account configuration in x-lite, it gets the ip from the public dns server ignoring the /etc/host file. Is there a way to force x-lite to use the local hosts file for dns lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one of the reasons that `x-lite` can still reach the domain is because you don't have a separate line with an IPv6 loopback (an IPv6 version of the `127.0.0.1` address the blocked domain currently redirects to). `x-lite` must be ignoring the IPv4 entry, and connecting to the blocked domain via an IPv6 address.

You can fix this by adding one line to your `/etc/hosts` file. A similar question [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/544789/why-cant-i-block-facebook-using-etc-hosts-on-mountain-lion) suggests that you use `fe80::1%lo0` as the IPv6 loopback address, as it says that OS X versions later than 10.8.2 won't respect the `::1` loopback address.

An example of the line you need to add to your host file is:

```
fe80::1%lo0 DOMAINTOBEBLOCKED.com
```

If this doesn't work, I would suggest having a look at some of the other answers on the question above. One that looks promising is:

> Try adding following line in /etc/resolv.conf
>
> `lookup file, bind`
>
> This should force OS X to use /etc/hosts before dns. The only problem
>   is if you use dhcp, this file will be overwrote each reboot.

Comment: @markus Did you try the instructions above? Did they work?