# How to block this facebook Like us slidebox?

Tags: blocking, popups

The facebook-widget-popup I want to remove is located at existenz.se (when scrolling down a bit, down to the right). It has an option to never show it again, but it keeps forgetting it every login (confirmed I'm not the only one)

I've tried all the suggestions here:

[How to block annoying facebook and other social network widgets](https://superuser.com/questions/361378/how-to-block-annoying-facebook-and-other-social-network-widgets)

Ghostery finds no trackers on the site.

Also here: [Blocking facebook's Like button in firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/144973/blocking-facebooks-like-button-in-firefox)

In noscript I can remove it by untrusting existenz.se, but that breaks a lot of functionality.

Tried inspect element and deleted what I thougth was the slidebox, but that ended up messsing up the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn off Adblock Plus because one of the rules in EasyList blocks it by default, so that's an option you can try.

Comment: Come again? How can one use easy list with Adblock plus off, when easy list is a filter that is added in adblock plus? Besides the slidebox seems to not be sent from a remote server; I've managed to block the facebook components, the box still shows up with headline and "never show this again" section. If you mean turn off ADP default list and only have easylist active I tried that too, didn't help.

Comment: What I meant was, ABP with EL blocks that slidebox by default and so in order to see it I had to temporarily disable ABP. I was suggesting you too could use ABP with EL.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the Firefox extension [Customize Your Web](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/customize-your-web/?src=ss) and removed the slidebox.